how to add custom css to 3CX live chat
i tried to add css to 3CX live chat but it's not working.
also tried to make it with js but also didn't work.
The browser doesn't detect the presence of css code.
/* --------------- Live Chat Css --------------- */
.minimized-button_EkBzy {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
.minimized-button_EkBzy svg rect {
    fill: #000 !important;
}
.root_PiWWB .powered-by_Qe9aP {
    display: none !important;
}
didn't work

// --js--
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var style = document.createElement('style');
            style.innerHTML = `
            .minimized-button_EkBzy {
                background-color: #ffffff !important;
            }
            .minimized-button_EkBzy svg rect {
                fill: #000 !important;
            }
            .root_PiWWB .powered-by_Qe9aP {
                display: none !important;
            }
            `;
            document.head.appendChild(style);
        });

didn't work
also tried this method:
<script>
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
     mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
       if (mutation.addedNodes.length) {
         mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(node) {
           if (node.nodeType === 1) {
             if (node.classList.contains('msg_bubble_t4lka')) {
               node.style.flexDirection = 'row-reverse';
             }
             if (node.classList.contains('root_sT5qE')) {
               const targetNodes = node.querySelectorAll('.msg_bubble_t4lka');
               targetNodes.forEach(function(targetNode) {
                 targetNode.style.flexDirection = 'row-reverse';
               });
             }
           }
         });
       }
     });
   });

   observer.observe(document.body, {
     childList: true,
     subtree: true
   });
 });
</script>

also didn't work
This is my html code:
enter image description here
After loading the page, he adds elements inside it and it becomes as shown in the picture:
enter image description here
is this possible to add custom css to the generated elements?

Are the elements you are trying to format there actually part of your own page - or does this chat component perhaps load into an iframe, from a different origin? If it is the latter, then you have no way of interfering with the content from your end; if the provider doesn't offer you any options/settings to achieve this, it won't be possible then.

I just updated my question, please see the image I added and tell me if I can add custom CSS without consulting the provider?

Since this is using a Shadow DOM, I don't think you will be able to manipulate anything from the outside - other than via what configuration options / settings this might offer.
